# JMeter - Folding options in Samplers

Tags: jmeter, folding

Inside Body Data of HTTP Sampler or JSR223 Sampler (or other Sampler )

I can Right click and get the following:

[image]

Copy/Paste/Cut/... functions work but Folding options seems to do nothing and irrelevant in that context

What [folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folding) is executing in this context? is it a specific feature for specific sampler?

I checked with code/XML/JSON and there's no impact on the text in field.

> Code folding is a feature of some text editors and IDEs that allow some text to be temporarily hidden or "collapsed" in order to hide detail.

**EDIT**

I found I can disable it by changing in jmeter.properties:

```
jsyntaxtextarea.codefolding=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature can hide anything that represents a "block" and is useful when you have a large lump of code, including comments, function definitions, possibly lengthy array definitions, but want to concentrate on main script flow instead. Anything that can be collapsed can be seeing by "minus in square" symbol [image] and anything that can be expanded has an opposite "plus in square" symbol [image]. You can expand or collapse using right-click menu items or by clicking that symbol.

Here's a primitive example when this can be useful.

Without folds:

[image]

As you can tell, I can't even see any runnable code without scrolling. But the way it's displayed below, I can tell what script is actually doing (which, btw, exposes one problem right away), and expand relevant parts to see more details if needed:

[image]